# Match whole word using SqlMethods.Like

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

My code is as follows with a regular expression in the like clause:

```
string f = "example";

var likestr = string.Format("%[^a-zA-Z]{0}[^a-zA-Z]%", f);

var q = SearchColumn.Where(x => SqlMethods.Like(x.Search_Col, likestr));
```

Although it returns values, it misses valid results out.

As an example, when searching for 'example' it'll find 'An Example Bank', but not find 'Example Personal Finance (EPF)'.

Comment: -1: the question is pretty useless without examples of which "valid results" it "misses out"

Comment: What is an actual value of `likestr` here?

Comment: @ChrisFarmer just edited my post.

Comment: But `likestr` can never take the value of "example" given your `string.Format` call.

Comment: And maybe you could describe what you're actually trying to accomplish with the character sets in your expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the problem is that your like **requires** a character other than a letter both before and after your search criteria and won't work if the criteria is at the start or end of your database field.

So if you search for Example, you find 'An Example Bank' , but not 'Example Bank'.

I'm not sure whether there is a faster way using Sql, but this should work.

```
var f = "example"'

var likestr1 = string.Format("%[^a-zA-Z]{0}[^a-zA-Z]%", f);
var likestr2 = string.Format("%[^a-zA-Z]{0}", f);
var likestr3 = string.Format("{0}[^a-zA-Z]%", f);


var q = SearchColumn.Where(x => 
           SqlMethods.Like(x.Search_Col, likestr1) || 
           SqlMethods.Like(x.Search_Col, likestr2) || 
           SqlMethods.Like(x.Search_Col, likestr3) ||
                          (x.Search_Col == f)
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use the Contains() method?

```
var f = "example"
var q = from x in MyTable where x.Search_Col.Contains(f) select x;
```